# For Loop to Convert a Base 2 Number to Base 10?

Tags: loops, for-loop, radix

So my teacher is having us work with for loops and one of our assignments is to make a for loop that will change any base 2 number to base 10. I'll post what I have done so far. I'm only in AP Computer Science to the code will look amateurish.

```
    public long getBaseTen( )
{
    long ten=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length()-1; i++)
    {
        if (binary.charAt(binary.length()-i-1) == '0');
            ten += 0;
        if (binary.charAt(binary.length()-i-1) == '1');
            ten += Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    return ten;
}
```

binary is a string variable that contains the base 2 number earlier specified by the user. I need to convert this base 2 string into base 10 and store that number into long ten. Right now whenever I call this method, I always get the same number depending on the length of the string. If the string is 2 letters long, it will always return a 1, if it's 3 letters long, it will always return a 3, if it's 4 letters long, it will always return a 7 and so on. Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Notice, i < binary.length()-1 it's wrong too. Check my answer below.

Comment: the `Math.pow(2,i)` could be replaced with a variable `long factor` starting as 1, then being multiplied by 2 for each turn (not only the turns where `char=='1'`).

Comment: Oh, there's a read method in the `Integer` class `Integer.parseInt(urString,2)` where 2 is the radix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that your if-statements closes to early:

```
if (binary.charAt(binary.length()-i-1) == '0');
           ten += 0;
```

should be

```
if (binary.charAt(binary.length()-i-1) == '0'){
           ten += 0;
}
```

There are, of course, some other things that could be done differently, but you'll figure that out along the way.

Comment: I can't believe I made such an obvious mistake and didn't catch it. That's embarrassing. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: No worry. The C-style syntaxen of if-statements are far from trivial.

Comment: This is another reason why I advocate *always* using `{}` with `if` statements, with the opening `{` on the same line as the `if` -- makes such a mistake a *little*  more obvous.  (An editor that automatically indents will help too, as it would not have indented the `ten += ...` statements, so they wouldn't have looked right.)

Comment: (About half of the "art" of programming is avoiding stupid mistakes.  The other half is finding the ones you didn't avoid.)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolons at the end of the "if" lines. They shouldn't be there; they're being interpreted as

```
 if(whatever)
     ; // null statement -- do nothing
```

(You could also add braces around the block of code controlled by the if, but that's optional when you're just trying to control a single statement. Some folks always use the braces, but that decision is very much a matter of coding style.)

Comment: You're right, that would work as well, I chosed to tell the more general way of embracing the statement(s) with `{ }`.

Comment: Updated to clarify. The semicolon is the problem. The braces help clarify and prevent future errors, but are optional and since the OP wasn't using them I saw no need to add them. De gustibus...

Answer (score 0):

A string of 0's and 1's follows a power of two rule. The right most value is 2^0 then 2^1 2^2 and so on the exponent doubling each time. Knowing this you can make an easy for loop to do the conversion.

For example:

```
 int tens;
 for(int i=1;i<binary.length()-1; i++){
    tens += Math.pow(2,binary.length-i);
 }
```

For example if the binary number is 0101 we know this to be 5. We will start at binary.length()-1 which would be 3, perfect since the right most value 0 is represented by 2^3. The second number 1 is represented by 2^2 which if you notice binary.length()-i at this point is 2.

If you follow the logic this should work, may need a small syntax fix.

Comment: yes, this (probably) works and is compact, which is very good. It may not be very quick and could be even be wrong in some circumstances. </say no more teacher mode>

Answer (score 0):

You are not need use one if statement, you can use this

```
public long getBaseTen()
{
    long ten=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++)
    {
        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1')
            ten += Math.pow(2,  binary.length()-i-1);
    }
    return ten;
}
```

Notice, `i < binary.length()-1` it's wrong too.

You can see how it works here http://ideone.com/swzitQ